# navbar is not full width

Tags: html, css

I am building my own portfolio/company site and my code is below I try to make it full width but it does not go full width. I am writing the code in html5 and css3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>TECH-EXPERTS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

  <body>

  <header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  </header>

</body>
</html>

nav{
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  line-height: 56px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover{
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: why should it be full width when u got ``width: 90%`` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you... what do you want to be full width? You are styling just one element (setting its width to 90%).

Answer (score 0):

First off, assuming that you want the navbar to span the entire width of the window, you need make sure that you're removing the default margin that is placed on the `body` element (if you are not using a css reset of some kind that already takes care of that).

Try:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Now remove the `width: 90%;` that's on your navbar.  That should get you pointed in the right direction.

[Here's a Codepen](http://codepen.io/ElijahFowler/pen/zvxJyK) of that in action.

Comment: @omiedbadr Glad I could help.  If my answer was satisfactory would you please mark it as the answer to your question?
Thanks, and have a great day.